# iText 7.1.8 for .net. Filling PdfFormFieldButton not working

Tags: .net, itext7, setvalue

I'm using iText7 7.1.8 for .net.

My pdf has 2 checkboxes with the same name and each having "English" and "French" for export values. These checkboxes are defined as /btn in the pdf. iText7 returns a PdfButtonFormField when I call form.GetField. When try to fill the value using SetValue, instead of checking the right button, it is overwriting the export value of one checkbox and also checking it. This is my code:

```
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(path), new PdfWriter(@"C:\test.pdf"));
var frm = GetAcroForm(pdf, true);
var form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdf, true);
var field = (iText.Forms.Fields.PdfButtonFormField) form.GetField("language");
// field.GetAppearanceStates()[2] is English
field.SetValue(field.GetAppearanceStates()[2]);
pdf.Close();
```

From the image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWirB.png, the English checkbox should be selected. Instead, French is select and the export value is changed from French to English.

Does anyone know what is going on?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share your PDF? Form fields are very much dependent on the PDF object structure you have in the document

Comment: Did you solve this? I have the same issue